# Access to specific domain from specific IP in local network

Tags: iptables, local-area-network, synology

I have in my local network some docker containers with firefox that running on different ports like 5801, 5802, etc.
So that only the device from which the launch was requested was accessible, i used the following command like this:

`iptables -I INPUT \! --src 1.2.3.4 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5801 -j DROP`

where `1.2.3.4` is a user IP.

But now i have made domain names for these containers. They work fine, but now anyone can connect to any container. So my question is, how do i allow only one user to access only one domain and drop everyone else?

For example:

- *user1* launch *container1* with domain name `sub1.domain.example`
- *user2* launch *container2* with domain name `sub2.domain.example`

And *user1* should only have access to `sub1.domain.example`; *user2* - only to `sub2.domain.example`.

I already tried to use ipset, but got this:
`ipset v6.23: Cannot open session to kernel.`

My server is a Synology NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're solving this on the wrong layer. Don't try to solve it on IP layer. That's just inflexible in most cases.

Implement some sort of authentication in the applications you serve, either directly, or with some authentication in front of it, such as [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy).

If you implement a proper frontend, you could even just have `example.com`, and redirect users behind the scenes based on privileges.